# run-time error '2147217911 (80040e09) [Cannot update. Database or object is read-only]

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I am using Microsoft Access VBA to build a cash flow generation tool. Unfortunately, the tool sometimes generate a run-time error

> '2147217911 (80040e09) [Cannot update. Database or object is
>   read-only]

after a number of deals are processed. This error is quite random and irregular as the tool does not always stop at a specific deal. Moreover, it only happens when multiple tools are working in parallel.

The underlying logic of this calculation is to open a linked cash flow database called `"tbl_CFDetail"` in a temporary `recordset` and keep adding new entry to the `recordset` in order to project the cash flows. I found that when this error is generated, the table `"tbl_CFDetail"` was kind of corrupted and was unable to add any new record.

Does anyone have any idea about this issue? What is the possible cause and the possible solution to it? Appreciate if anyone could help. Thank you!

Below is the script in error:

```
rst_CFDetail.AddNew
```

Comment: I think you forgot to add the script?  There's only a single line of code showing.

Comment: In `tbl_CFDetail` do you have a text field which you have used to join other table, while creating update query?

Comment: This error shows, that currently edited table is locked by another process. Sometimes it's really hard to find the root cause of this locking, it depends on the number of conditions

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook. Yes I wish to post the whole script here. However, it is just too long as the tool is used to calculate the risk exposure of a large bank. Just want to see if anyone has any previous experience on this error with the above background first.

Comment: I've used `AddNew` before if that counts as previous experience.  I think it depends on the table as well - is it local or linked, does it have an index, is the recordset from a query - is it an updatable query, do you have write permission for the database back-end & probably 101 other things I haven't thought of/come across before.

Comment: @Santosh
No, "tbl_CFDetail" does not have a text field to join other tables. Below is more background:The deals will be broken down into 10,000 deals per package. After cash flows are generated in this table for each package, the cash flow details will be aggregated and put in another table and the cash flows will be removed after the aggregation. This process will be repeated for each package until the cash flow generation for all packages are completed.